# Remove /web from PLEX URL

Tags: apache, http, url, web, remote-access

How do I remove the need to type /web on the end of my PLEX media server to access from outside my network? I have a no-ip.com account and set up a static domain name to point to a static ip. But that doesn't help much, because I still need to type in the /web to access my media server. I am using windows 7. I have set up a owncloud server before and removed the need to type /owncloud in the httpd.conf file. But I can't find it for the plex server. I read somewhere to set up a page that will redirect to /web, but I don't know how to do that. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

You can remove both the port (in case you are already not forwarding it from port 80 to Plex's port) and the need for the /web at end using redirection rules.

Here is a good example of how to do just that (this solution uses Apache):

http://matt.coneybeare.me/how-to-map-plex-media-server-to-your-home-domain/

*EDIT*: Small correction, that site I linked is not using redirection rules, it is using a reverse proxy.

With a redirection rule if you type: myPlexServer.com, you'll be redirected to myPlexServer.com:32400/web (as in, the address on your browser will actually be re-written to that, same as clicking on a link that takes you to another page).

With a reverse proxy, you effectively have a man in the middle, the reverse proxy server itself. You send requests to myPlexServer.com (Apache server in this case), it receives those requests and the proxy forwards them to myPlexServer.com:32400/web (PMS Server). The PMS server sends the reply to the Apache server and the Apache server sends the reply back to you. As far as PMS is concerned, the client requesting info is the Apache server, in fact it doesn't even know about you talking to the Apache server.